# Horizontal menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, menu

I began to learn HTML, CSS and Javascript 2 weeks ago and I'm stuck at this.

What i want is simply show the submenu when the menu is clicked.

I've read a lot about these. I've even found some similar questions but i just can't use the scripts.

It just don't work.

Here's the HTML.

```
<body>

  <ul id="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li><a href="#">Serv 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Serv 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Serv 2</a></li>
        </ul>

     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li><a href="#">Prod 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Prod 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Prod 2</a></li>
        </ul>

     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Customer</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Here is the Fiddle for it : http://jsfiddle.net/skV4h/, with the CSS and jQuery.

I'd be glad if anyone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works if you remember to include jQuery and close your code properly http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/skV4h/4/

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues, your JavaScript code doesn't end properly, it should be `})` instead of just `}`, also you're not including jQuery on your fiddle, finally your `.submenu` elements will overlap if you click one `li` with `.submenu` after the other, and the way it is right now it'll only affect your first `.submenut`. Also, it's better if you bind the `.click()` function to `#menu` specifically, otherwise your code will be triggered when you click other `li` elements as well. You can change your code to this:

```
$( '#menu').click(function () {  
    $submenu = $( this ).children( '.submenu' );
    if ( $submenu.is( ':hidden' ) ) {
            $submenu.slideDown( 'slow' );
            $('.submenu').not($submenu).hide();
        } else {
            $submenu.hide();
        }
});
```

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/skV4h/9/)**

Answer (score 1):

this code works form me

```
**HTML**

    <div class="navigation">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Consulting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Information</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


**CSS**
h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
}
body {
  color:#333;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li a {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #069;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    color: #069;
}

/*=== submenu ===*/

.nav ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
}

.nav ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #069;
}


**SCRIPT**


/*  jQuery ready function. Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.  */
$(document).ready(
  /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
  function () {
    /* Next part of code handles hovering effect and submenu appearing */
    $('.nav li').hover(
      function () { //appearing on hover
        $('ul', this).fadeIn();
      },
      function () { //disappearing on hover
        $('ul', this).fadeOut();
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i change it a bit cause it didn't work anyway.

**html**

```
 <title>Example</title>

      <ul id="menu">
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
               <li><a href="#">Serv 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Serv 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Serv 2</a></li>
            </ul>

         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
               <li><a href="#">Prod 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Prod 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Prod 2</a></li>
            </ul>

         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Customer</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
```

**css**

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

ul{
   list-style:none;
}

ul#menu{
   width:500px;
   margin:0 auto;
   position:relative;
}
ul#menu li{
   float:left;

}
ul#menu li a{
   display:block;
   float:left;
   padding:0 15px;
   height:25px;
   line-height:25px;
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#333;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}

ul#menu li a:hover, ul#menu li a.ativo{
   background:#ccc;
}

ul#menu li ul{
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   top:25px;
   left:0;
   width:460px;
   background:#ccc;
}
```

**js**

```
$( 'li').click(function () {  
    $(".submenu").hide();

    if ( $( '.submenu' ).is( ':hidden' ) ) {
            $(this).find(".submenu").slideDown( 'slow' );
        } 
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skV4h/11/)

Comment: Html and css is the same. I change only js.